# Using kubectl set image to update image of initContainer

Tags: kubernetes

Currently, to update a k8s deployment image, we use the `kubectl set image` command like this:

```
kubectl set image deployment/deployment_name container=url_to_container
```

While this command updates the URL used for the main container in the deployment, it does not update the URL for the `initContainer` also set within the deployment.

Is there a similar `kubectl` command I can use to update the `initContainer` to the same URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) seems to suggests that only containers are concerned.

Maybe you could switch to `kubectl patch` ?

(I know it's more tedious...)

```
kubectl patch deployment/deployment_name --patch "{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"spec\": {\"initContainers\": [{\"name\": \"container_name\",\"image\": \"url_to_container\"}]}}}}"
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, seems to be the least bad way to do it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

Since the accepted answer, the team [developed](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/72276) the ability to set image for Kubernetes init containers. Using the same command, simply use the init container name for the container part of the command you supplied.

```
kubectl set image deployment/deployment_name myInitContainer=url_to_container
```

In case you want to update both container images in a single command, use:

```
kubectl set image deployment/deployment_name myInitContainer=url_to_container container=url_to_container
```

Comment: This answer should be the preferred one as of now.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet above is based on solution provided by @Hiruma. Therefore, here I removed the empty spaces on the json argument and added a namespace example.

I did that because I faced issues when I was writing a pipeline for drone.io.

```
kubectl patch deployment deployment_name -n namespace_name -p  "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"initContainers\":[{\"name\":\"deployment_name\",\"image\":\"url_to_container"}]}}}}"
```